# Get length of array inside parameter list in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I would like to use length of provided array inside parameters list. I tried

```
def find(xs: Array[Double], m:Int = xs.length*2) = ???
```

,but xs is not accessible for *m* parameter. 
Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: you can get the length of the array when its initialized either at the time of calling find function or inside find function. I don't think you can get the length inside parameter list like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining default values of arguments, you can refer only to variables in the previous argument lists. Therefore, you need two argument lists:

```
def find(xs: Array[Double])(m: Int = xs.size * 2) = ???
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
find(Array(1, 2, 3))(6)
```

and

```
find(Array(1, 2, 3))()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case an ugly alternative is to use an invalid length as the default:

```
def find(xs: Array[Double], _m: Int = -1) = {
  val m = if (_m >= 0) _m else xs.length
```